# A word for "technify"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for a word to convey the meaning that you are going to develop a technology around something.

"Technify" is something I made up that embodies the concept quite well, but it's not a real word.

Can you think of any alternatives?

Comment: This would benefit from a more concrete example. Presumably, the 'something' you're going to develop a technology around is not already a technological product or service.

Comment: I'm not at all sure what you mean by "develop a technology around something." When people discover or develop something, they name it and it's a particular thing. This is so abstract as to be essentially meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Technify" is actually a real accepted word. In lexico.com:

**technify**
To make technical; to adopt or cause to adopt technology or technical methods.

A synonym can be "mechanize", although it doesn't clearly refer to the process of developing a technology.